# Millisecond resolution timer on LinkIT 7688

Tags: linux, timer, embedded, embedded-linux, clock

I am developing for the LinkIt Smart 7688 device by Mediatek. I need to do some timekeeping in a userspace application where I need at least 10ms resolution (preferably 1ms).

However every syscall I have tried returns values only with 1 second resolution. `clock_gettime` (tried all the different clocks) and `gettimeofday` which should provide sub-second resolution does not.

Doing a `dmesg` on the target reveals that the kernel timestamps with a resolution below 1 second, thus I conclude that a clock source is available with sub second resolution. (I would be very surpriced if this was not the case :) )

**How do I get a timestamp with sub-second resolution on the Linkit Smart 7688 device?**

Perhaps I could be missing some kernel configuration selecting the correct clock source to be available to userspace? I have not been able to find one.

Comment: You should know the drill for this site: show your code that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do not only use the seconds returned by gettimeofday, but also usec

```
gettimeofday(&t0, 0);
/* ... */
gettimeofday(&t1, 0);
long elapsed = (t1.tv_sec-t0.tv_sec)*1000000 + t1.tv_usec-t0.tv_usec;
```

Comment: The returned `struct timeval.tv_usec` is always zero on this platform.